# Why do Georgia font descenders break at the bottom of the characters in a Word document created on a PC and edited on macOS?

Tags: fonts

I am having an issue with a Word document that is created on a PC and edited by me in macOS.

I am the tech editor and am on Mac OS Monterey. The writer uses a PC and I don’t know what version of Word she has. My copy on Mac is OK, but yesterday we worked on her computer and that is when the change occurred.

What happens Georgia font descenders are broken, but not always, at the bottom of most characters.

For example, the bottom of the lowercase letter “g” is missing on an inconsistent basis. Numbers are also affected.

Sometime during editing this doc, the descenders started to go weird.

I’ve clicked Paragraph, Spacing, and then line spacing and checked “Exactly” and that seems to fix it, but how did they get that way in the first place?

Comment: I don't notice any such effect on my computers running Word 2016 and Word 2019. Check things like Paragraph>Line Spacing and make sure it's not set to 1.0 or less (the default on Word 2016 seems to be 1.08; I generally modify the default document template to use 1.10 instead, as that seems to be recommended in many typesetting discussions).

Comment: I'll look again at the line spacing; I thought it was set correctly. Thank you.

Comment: @AGreenaker Cool! But please add Word versions for the PC and macOS versions of Word involved here. Perhaps this is a line spacing issue. But this might be something else related to how the PC version of Word deals with things versus how the macOS version of Word deals with things.

Comment: Right now I'm not sure of anything. We made things work well enough, and none of the numbers lag below the baseline. Most of the g's are intact. I really think it's switching between Mac and PC that messed us up. Thanks for your input.